# i want to schedule one function in my controller every 5 minutes that is inserting files and product data in the DB.. how can i do that?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

here is how data is updating in the DB with the page refresh but i want it to update automaticaaly after every 5 minutes so that without refreshing my data becomes visables on welcome page as well as the data is inserted automatically on function call(that should be after every 5 minutes). i am a beginner i tried to learn from laravel documentation but its not exactly displaying what i need..
your help will be appriciated... here is the code of how i am inserting data in the DB:

```
         foreach($files as $file){
            if (Invoice::where('file_name', '=', $file['file_name'])->exists()) {
            }
            else {
            $store = new Invoice;
            $store->file_name = $file['file_name'];
            $store->name = $file['customer_name'];
            $store->po_no = $file['po'];
            $store->address = $file['city'];
            $store->total_items = count($file['products']);
            $store->save();
            $invid = $store->id;

            for($x = 0; $x < count($file['products']); $x++)
            {
                $pstore = new InvoiceProduct;
                $pstore->product_name = $file['products'][$x];
                $pstore->invoice_id = $invid;
                $pstore->quantity =$file['count'][$x];
                $pstore->barcode=$file['scan'][$x];
                $pstore->vendor_code =$file['vn'][$x];
                $pstore->save();
             }
        }
```

and the function name is index i want to schedule this function every 5 minutes.. Thank you!

Comment: Use cron job or scheduler for the above task.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling might help

Comment: I already watched some of the videos and documentation but as a beginner, I am not sure how can i do that, and none of that tells about controller side of scheduling

Comment: There is no controller side of scheduling. Scheduled tasks run in the background without needing any user interaction. It's not clear if this is what you want or if you want the page to automatically show a user who is using it any updates every 5 minutes which that would be achieved via something like AJAX (maybe you need both we just can't know without further details)

Answer (score 0):

first open command console go to the root of your Laravel project and type:

```
php artisan make:command MyNewCommand // Choose name as you wish. in this example is MyNewCommand
```

New file created in **app\Console\Commands**. Open it and in function **handle** call your related controller and in the same time choose in name for your command:

```
 protected $signature = 'auto:cron';

public function handle()
    {
      call('App\Http\Controllers\MyRelatedController@relatedFunction')->everyFiveMinutes();  
 
    }
```

Go to the **app\Console** and open **Kernel.php**
add in the class Kernel this command:

```
protected $commands = [            
            Commands\MyNewCommand::class
        ];
```

in this file in function **schedule** add your related controller:

```
$schedule->command('auto:cron')
             ->everyFiveMinutes();
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\MyRelatedController@relatedFunction')
                ->everyFiveMinutes();
```

At the end add your command to server cron job. Change this in order to your current PHP path and your Laravel project path:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/myaccount/public_html/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I have done all the steps in the last step you mean i should run php artisan schedule:run ...right?

Comment: but when I run php artisan schedule:run it only executed single time and then closed

Comment: Please check my last edit and test your server cron job too

Comment: You can run schedule:run only for testing. If you want that server do it for you every 5 minutes you should add last command to your server cron.

Comment: 'auto:cron' is failing
here is the error appearing in the terminal:
  2022-08-31 11:07:37 Running ["artisan" auto:cron] ..................................................................................... 639ms FAIL
  ⇂ "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "artisan" auto:cron > "NUL" 2>&1  
  2022-08-31 11:07:38 Running [App\Http\Controllers\DataController@index] ................................................................ 76ms DONE

Comment: I see typos. Why you changed the command? Check it on a real server. I don't know how to setup cron for XAMPP. My example works on a linux server.

Comment: my command name is different its db_update... i will check cron for xampp thank you

Answer (score 0):

After making the command and adding it to kernel, if it for testing, you can run "php artistan schedule:work"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).